# How to handle action state "INCOMPLETE"

Tags: salesforce, apex, aura-framework

The example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm has

```
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
 .......
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
 ......
```

What should "do something" be?

I've seen so many examples with "do something", including the code I wrote, that I'd thought I should stop doing this (copy and paste) and do something about it, pun intended.